# Heroku Slug Files

Tags: heroku

I am looking to minimize my slug size for Heroku.  I was looking over the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) and noticed that Heroku will:

> Download, build, and install local dependencies as specified in your
>   build file (for example, Gemfile, package.json, requirements.txt,
>   pom.xml, etc.) with the dependency management tool supported by the
>   language (e.g. Bundler, npm, pip, Maven).

Are these dependencies included in my slug size?  If so, will my [.slugignore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-) entries apply to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dependencies are downloaded and packaged with your app to form the slug so they do count towards the slug size.

I don't believe `.slugignore` exclusions apply to dependencies, only to files in your app repo. Excluding downloaded dependencies from the slug would cause your app to fail since they're required for your application to run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What if I want to exclude static files from my dependencies?  I'm collecting the static files independently and loading them up on, say, S3.  Can I remove these files from my dependencies somehow?

Comment: You can. They won't be available via asset pipeline, but if you have big assets it may make more sense to put them on S3.